# 20.04 shutdown suddenly but not restart

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, asus, overheating, restart

there is a kind of difficult situation here. I just installed ubuntu and used it for a few hours. All of a sudden, the laptop screen went blank. it stopped responding. I pressed shutdown. It was hot.

Now I tried to restart, it is not starting.

I plugged in, but no LED responding.

I even pressed the power button for 40 seconds,  both before disconnecting the battery and after.
Nothing works.

Please suggest if you have anything.

Model: ASUS TUF FX504 gaming laptop

**Update**

Thanks for comments. I understand it’s hardware problem. The exact same issue happened with me 6 months, it was in warranty so got motherboard changed.

It don’t believe it to be mere coincidence that same happened twice. After repairing it was working fine, until yesterday when i again installed ubuntu.

Just after installation

- system temperature went high even when nothing was running.
- High rate of battery depletion
- Fan running at high speed.

It is sad to say I have to leave using ubuntu and go for another linux distribution or WSL2

- can’t afford another laptop
- Can’t afford damage after installing ubuntu

I have my own doubts that there is something wrong in linux distribution after may 2020. I was using ubuntu for nearly a year before on current system and heating issue was not there. After may 2020 heating went high even though nothing was running. Yesterday I installed again and paid the cost.

---

### **Update2**

If anyone else had the issue of heat, here is what i found helps

- don't use nvidia gpu's. disable them or make them on demand.
- Don't use nvidia gpu's for display.
- be warned if your laptop temp's is rising. Shutdown and let it cool.

Comment: Same thing happened in 6 months ago. I got it repaired. It was working fine with windows till now. After installing ubuntu, it’s happening again. I mean why ?

Comment: No. OS was loaded. It happened after few hours running of ubuntu.

Comment: "*but it is not starting*" seems to mean no OS (off-topic). Guessing why it failed in the past without any data or logs is merely guessing (unanswerable). If it was hot, maybe the fans weren't working. Maybe the shop shorted out the thermal sensors. Maybe the heat melted the solder off one motherboard connection. Maybe a capacitor in the charger failed. Maybe lots of possibilities. Insufficient data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments. I understand it’s hardware problem. The exact same issue happened with me 6 months, it was in warranty so got motherboard changed.

It don’t believe it to be mere coincidence that same happened twice. After repairing it was working fine, until yesterday when i again installed ubuntu.

Just after installation

- system temperature went high even when nothing was running.
- High rate of battery depletion
- Fan running at high speed.

It is sad to say I have to leave using ubuntu and go for another linux distribution or WSL2

- can’t afford another laptop
- Can’t afford damage after installing ubuntu

I have my own doubts that there is something wrong in linux distribution after May 2020. I was using ubuntu for nearly a year before on current system and heating issue was not there. After may 2020 heating went high even though nothing was running. Yesterday I installed again and paid the cost.